# Error using make on Windows with MinGW

Tags: c, cmd, mingw

I'm fairly new to using "make" for anything, but I am forced to try and build some binaries with it for some C files (the code is not mine). It works for most of the files in the directory, but when it reaches the "usb" directory this happens:

```
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/bios_memimage/usb'
/bin/rm -fr scraper.bin
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /bin/rm -fr scraper.bin, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'scraper.bin' failed
make[1]: *** [scraper.bin] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/bios_memimage/usb'
Makefile.mingw:14: recipe for target 'subdirusb' failed
make: *** [subdirusb] Error 2
```

I'm unfamiliar with what "bin/rm -fr" means, and looking for it has not yielded much of anything. I can tell it's not creating the process, but what, exactly is it failing to find? And is there a remedy for it?

Comment: Try adding the directory where `/bin` is in to the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: If you mean the MinGW bin, I've already done so when I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

That line tries to delete certain filenames during the build.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153336/what-does-bin-rm-f-file-do-in-unix

Remove those lines in the makefile because they obviously will not work on windows. If the files must be deleted for the build to proceed, then replace the lines with windows equivalents.